# how to give input from array whenever it ask input from keyboard in java

Tags: java

Suppose i have a class named Invoked, to which i want to call using reflection from Invoker class. but i want to give input from array declared in Invoker class whenever it gets code for input from keyboard.

```
class Invoked {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner();
        // here i want to give input stored in array except of console from Invoker class.
        System.out.println("input given from keyboard is : " + s.next());
    }
}

class Invoker {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        // i want to pass array here for keyboard input values like
        Class<?> cl = loader.loadClass("Invoked");
        Method m = cl.getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] {String[].class });
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(null, new Object[] {null });

    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by *give input from array*?

Comment: i want to make an online java compiler, so Invoked class will be given from user. i want to provide facility for keyboard input which user will give in a textbox before execution and will be stored in an array. now whenever it gets code for keyboard input, it provide input for that from array programatically. Please tell me alternate solution also if u have. Thanks.

Comment: I think you don't need scanner,if you are passing values from user input as array to method. _Why don't you directly use array elements?_

Comment: the code of Scanner will be written by user, who use my online java compiler. i can not change that code.  i just want to take input from user before execution. so that i will push this value for input whenever keyboard input will be asked at execution time.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Scanner()` reads by default from `System.in` [stop: there is no default constructor in Scanner, your code won't compile]. You can set it to eg a StringInputStream right before invoking of main ([System.setIn()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream))).

```
class Invoked{
public static void main(String ar[])
{
java.util.Scanner s=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
//here i want to give input stored in array except of console from Invoker class.
System.out.println("input given from keyboard is : "+s.next());
}
}

class Invoker
{
public static void main(String ar[])
{
//i want to pass array here for keyboard input values like 
Class<?> cl = loader.loadClass("Invoked");
Method m=cl.getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
m.setAccessible(true);
System.setIn(new StringBufferInputStream("a b 100"));
m.invoke(null, new Object[] { null });

}

}
```

Comment: In above code i forgot to write System.in, that line was actually Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);  we can not change in this line because this code will be given from user randomly. actually i want to create online java compiler. please read all the requirement in comment, which i wrote below question.

Comment: thank you. your code is working. but please give vote for my question.

Comment: Yes i will do so, but right now i have less than 15 reputation as i am new. i will accept for this as soon i get 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList to make a dynamic array based off how many lines the user inputs.

```
class Invoked {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>;
        while(s.hasNext()) {
             input.add(s.next());
        for(String i : input)
             System.out.println("input given from keyboard is : " + i);
    }
}
```

To convert the ArrayList to an array, use

```
String inArray = input.toArray();
```

Comment: i can not take input from keyboard at runtime. it is my condition. i want to keep value in an array. whenever we get any code at runtime like s.next(). i will fulfill this input from array except of console. please hava a look again. thanks.

Comment: and i can not write our logic in Invoked class. pls write logic in Invoker class whatever required.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact code for my problem. Here is the code given below.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
class Invoked{
public static void main(String ar[])
{
java.util.Scanner s=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("input given from keyboard is : "+s.next());
int i=s.nextInt()+s.nextInt();
System.out.println("input given from keyboard is : "+i);
}
}

class Invoker
{
public static void main(String ar[])throws Exception
{
Class<?> cl = Class.forName("Invoked");
Method m=cl.getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
m.setAccessible(true);
String inputString="ashish 15 16";
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputString.getBytes()));
m.invoke(null, new Object[] { null });
}
}
```